# Is it possible to pass some data to PHP script which is called thru header('Location: ')

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which invokes another PHP script thru header("Location:"). Is it possible to pass some data to that second script, e.g. login name. That second script uses POST as its form's method. Currently  I pass data thru file on server

Comment: you sure can, did you search for it? did you try anything? do you have code?

Comment: I found some code and it passes info to another script thru text files

Comment: You can hand over simple HTTP GET parameters, obviously. Or you store the data in a session. It is not possible to somehow simulate a HTTP POST request this way.

Comment: So that means that passing data thru text files on server's filesystem is the best way?

Comment: There's at least 3 ways to do this. Either via query parameters, session data or by storing data in a shared storage place (e.g. hard drive). I'd opt for GET query parameters. It's the simplest way.

Comment: Without knowing the purpose, it's not possible to provide you the best answer. However - in most cases a session is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this basically just redirects the browser to the url specified in your `Location` header you can not simulate a `POST` request here.
What you can do is to send `GET`-parameters with the requets.

For example you could do this:

```
<?php
header("Location: nextpage.php?login_name=".$login_name);
```

Then you would access this in the nextpage.php code with `$_GET['login_name']`.

Comment: You can also use $_SESSION to save data in, then pull it on the other side. Wouldnt pass any sensitive data through GET parameters.

Comment: passing `$login_name` per `GET` parameter seams to be very wrong.